# Parsing a list of strings followed by a list of strings with spirit x3

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am trying to parse a string into a struct using boost spirit x3:

```
struct identifier {
    std::vector<std::string> namespaces;
    std::vector<std::string> classes;
    std::string identifier;

};
```

now I have a parser rule to match a strings like this:

```
foo::bar::baz.bla.blub
foo.bar
boo::bar
foo
```

my parser rule looks like this.

```
auto const nested_identifier_def =
        x3::lexeme[
                -(id_string % "::")
                >> -(id_string % ".")
                >> id_string
        ];
```

where `id_string` parses combinations of `alphanum`.
I know this rule doesnt work to parse as I want it, because while parsing `foo.bar` for example this part of the rule `-(id_string % ".")` consumes the whole string.
How can i change the rule to parse correctly in the struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `id_string` is something like this:

```
auto const id_string = x3::rule<struct id_string_tag, std::string>{} =
    x3::lexeme[
            (x3::alpha | '_')
        >> *(x3::alnum | '_')
    ];
```

then I think this is what you're after:

```
auto const nested_identifier_def =
       *(id_string >> "::")
    >> *(id_string >> '.')
    >>  id_string;
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70373eb04b146bd6)</kbd>

The issue is that `p % delimit` is shorthand for `p >> *(delimit >> p)`, i.e. it always consumes one `p` *after* the delimiter. However what you want is `*(p >> delimit)` so that no `p` is consumed after the delimiter and is instead left for the next rule.